# How can I view the source control changes view for the currently active editor in VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, I have several files, all named index.ts. From time to time I want to have a look at the diff of the currently opened file.

Is it possible to have an open file selected in the source control window so I immediately know which file selected in the source control window is the one I am working on currently?

I'm imagining something like right-clicking on the open file's tab and then selecting **Show in Source Control**, analogous to Show in Explorer. Is there already a plugin for this or another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "Open Changes" button ([image]/[image]) at the top right of the tab bar, or use the `Git: Open Changes` command in the command palette.